# How to boot from USB on a 32 bit asus laptop?

Tags: bios, linux-mint, bootable-media, asus-laptop

For some time now, I have been trying to boot Linux Mint from a flash drive on my 32 bit Windows Asus laptop. The problem is there is absolutely no boot options​ only windows boot manager, and to top that, I can't enable csm or legacy. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide screenshot of boot menu?

Comment: Yes I willhold on

Comment: Terribly sorry I don't have enough reputation I'll have to describe it , I'm under the boot tab and the only thing there is "boot option no1 : windows boot manager"

Comment: Try using a different USB port in case that one isn't functional. You can post the screenshot on https://prnt.sc/ and comment the link.

Comment: You shouldn't have to enable CSM in order to boot Mint, Mint has fully support for UEFI, we need more information to answer your question.

Comment: Also, to double check, did you use linux mint 32bit, like this:  https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=238.  And, how did you create the bootable usb (did you use rufus https://rufus.akeo.ie)?

Comment: Can you get into BIOS? Esc, F2, F10, del? Is it Win10? If its win10 you could boot into bios from recovery settings, and enable legacy boot. Once you can get into the bios, you may need to change some settings.

Comment: Ok first yes I use f2 to boot into BIOS, second I am completely sure I have the right Linux distribution and I used Win32diskImager to write it and yes it is windows 10  here's the screenshot : http://prntscr.com/gd5od9  oh and it only has one port so

Comment: You probably need a 32-bit UEFI bootloader, e.g. grub i386-efi.

Comment: @LeoFoster, First, something is wrong in your system, so can I please suggest that you do not write "I am ... sure I have the right Linux distr...".  Instead, tell us which you have.  You can only be sure when it is working.  Second, the recommended way to create a bootable usb image on Windows, is to use Rufus (see https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).  Win32diskImager might work, but it is not the recommended tool, so you're on your own if you want to try making it work.  Combination of Rufus and the right Linux image will certainly work, so any other issues should be with your BIOS.

Comment: Ok thank you @jehad the Linux I downloaded was Linux mint 32 bit cinnamon and I'll try writing the flashdrive with Rufus , I really appreciate all of you guys help :)

Comment: Update : I burned the flash drive with Rufus and now it shows up in the boot menu  but when I try to set it for first it skips it and goes on to windows

Comment: Happy to help.  Can you please take a picture of your bios boot options?  Also, which Asus laptop do you have?  It's possible that you selected the wrong boot option (I think there should be both a UEFI and a BIOS legacy option on the same usb drive).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the following two resources:

1)  A **32-bit OS image**:  E.g. [Linuxmint 32bit](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=238)

and,

2)  A recommended method of **creating a bootable USB drive**.  E.g [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) provides a [tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), which recommends using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).